# Constructing chemical equations

Tags: stoichiometry

When constructing chemical equations, how can you work out the subscript of each product. For example:

$$\ce{3Ca  +  N2-> Ca3N2}$$

How do I know that it's $\ce{Ca}$ with a little 3 and N with a little 2.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Those subscripts come from the minimum number of calcium and nitride ions needed to product a charge-balanced neutral ionic compound. Here is a related question on nomenclature of binary compounds that covers some of the basics: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98159/how-to-name-binary-inorganic-compounds-given-their-chemical-formula-and-vice

Comment: For more information on the linear algebra check out the book "Chemical Reaction Equilibrium Analysis: Theory and Algorithms" by Missen & Smith.

Answer (score 1):

When constructing chemical equations, you cannot work out the subscript of each product. The formula cannot be guessed. In your example, you must know the formula $\ce{Ca, N2}$ and $\ce{Ca3N2}$. This being given, your job is to find the good coefficients 3, 1 and 1.

Comment: I hope nobody thinks that people study chemistry to make their living after graduation in a job where they balance equations all day as their prime task.